# Run time error '2046' access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo un problema con el siguiente codigo

```
 With doCmd
   .RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
   .RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
   .RefreshRecord
 End With
```

Me da como error:

> Run time error '2046', the command or action 'DeleteRecord' isn't
>   available now.

Ya verifiqué toda las conexiones, permisos y demás pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, mi aplicación en Access 2016 se conecta con SQL server 18.4

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. ¿Dónde estás intentando ejecutar este código? Supongo que en un formulario. ¿Qué origen de datos tiene?

Comment: Hola Elier, como comentas estoy aplicando este codigo en un formularios, el origen de datos esta en una base de datos en SQL

Comment: Sí, pero el registro que no te deja borrar ¿es de una tabla? ¿De una consulta? ¿La estás abriendo con permisos de escritura? ¿Has puesto en permisos del formulario que te deje borrar?

Comment: Lo solucine justo ayer, el registro es de una tabla, tenia todos los permisos pero no me dejaba hacer nada por el tipo de dato que tenia en una columna no hacia match.